# error processing package python3-pip (--configure) ubuntu 20.04 focal fossa

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu-20.04

```
~$ sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
3 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up python3-setuptools (45.2.0-1) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-setuptools.postinst: 6: py3compile: not found
dpkg: error processing package python3-setuptools (--configure):
 installed python3-setuptools package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 127
Setting up python3-wheel (0.34.2-1) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-wheel.postinst: 6: py3compile: not found
dpkg: error processing package python3-wheel (--configure):
 installed python3-wheel package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 127
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-pip:
 python3-pip depends on python3-setuptools; however:
  Package python3-setuptools is not configured yet.
 python3-pip depends on python3-wheel; however:
  Package python3-wheel is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-pip (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                          Errors were encountered while processing:
 python3-setuptools
 python3-wheel
 python3-pip
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```